# google search engine architecture- how do so many concurrent users do a search on it

Tags: search-engine, yahoo

With millions of users searching for so many things on google, yahoo and so on.
How can the server handle so many concurrent searches?
I have no clue as to how they made it so scalable.
Any insight into their architecture would be welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One element, [DNS load balancing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round_robin_DNS).

There are plenty of resources on google architecture, this site has a nice list:

- http://highscalability.com/google-architecture

Comment: @GezaKerecsenyi, thanks - removed. It seems google currently uses a DNS load balancing, that moves more control to Google, in that they only give out a single IP (as opposed to multiple ones, as a few years ago) - that single google IP is request IP dependent - so they can more predictable shift loads around.

Answer (score 4):

DNS Load Balancing is correct, but it is not really the full answer to the question. Google uses a multitude of techniques, including but not limited to the following:

- DNS Load Balancing (suggested)
- Clustering - as suggested, but note the following

  - clustered databases (the database storage and retrieval is spread over many machines)
  - clustered web services (analogous to DNSLB here)
  - An internally developed clustered/distributed filing system
- Highly optimised search indices and algorithms, making storage efficient and retrieval fast across the cluster
- Caching of requests (squid), responses (squid), databases (in memory, see shards in the above article)

Answer (score 3):

I've gone searching for information about this topic recently and [Wikipedia's Google Platform article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_platform) was the best all around source of information on how Google does it. However, the High Scalability blog has outstanding articles on scalability nearly every day. Be sure to check it out their [Google architecture article](http://highscalability.com/google-architecture) too.

Answer (score 1):

The primary concept in most of the highly scalable applications is [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_%28computing%29).

Some resources regarding the cluster architecture of different search engines.

- http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/labs.google.com/en//papers/googlecluster-ieee.pdf
- https://opencirrus.org/system/files/OpenCirrusHadoop2009.ppt

You can also read interesting research articles at [Google Research](http://www.google.com/research/) and [Yahoo Research](http://research.yahoo.com/).